# Express.js App Deployment: Invalid command 'PassengerAppRoot', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, express, deployment, cpanel

I want to deploy an express.js app on cPanel. I installed node, nvm and npm successfully. I manage to upload all files to the server and configure the .htaccess file. However, cPanel error logs it pop the error above.

I've tried adding quotes on directory paths etc. but nothing helped yet.

This is my htaccess file:

```
PassengerBaseURI /
PassengerAppRoot /home/evces1uld3jn/myapp
PassengerAppType node
PassengerStartupFile app.js
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by changing htaccess file to

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex disabled
RewriteRule ^$ http://127.0.0.1:50000/ [P,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:50000/$1 [P,L]
```

where 50000 is the corresponding port number in the app.